# Oracle - View function body from a package

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a function inside of a package in Oracle and am wanting to view the implementation or the body of one of the functions.

I can find the package in the `all_source` view but cannot find the function. I have also tired the `user_source` view.

**Is the function details located in a different view or table?** I know it can be done as I found it yesterday but stupidly did not save the query...

`Note`

I want to view the body of the function inside the package not the body of the package itself

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986544/sqlplus-query-issue-package-spec-and-body

Comment: No, as I mentioned I cannot find the function inside of the all_source table

Comment: are you selecting the package name with `type = 'PACKAGE BODY'`?

Comment: The body of the function is part of the body of the package. It doesn't exist as a separate entity.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find the package body in `all_source` view.

```
  SELECT *
    FROM all_source
   WHERE TYPE = 'PACKAGE BODY' AND name = '<your package name>'
ORDER BY line;
```

I think you are probably trying to search using function name and not able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use this context

```
SELECT *
FROM all_source
WHERE TYPE = 'PACKAGE' 
AND name = '<your package name>'
ORDER BY line;
```

but change the type to just PACKAGE